# QWidget how to detect mouse stop moving

Tags: qt, qwidget, qmouseevent

I can do something when mouse is moving by overwriting QWidget's mouseMoveEvent function.

But I want to do something at the moment when mouse stop moving. How can I implement this?

Comment: Add some code, what have you tried so far? Are you having any issues with implementing it or are you just unsure? If you're unsure, I recommend taking the time to do your own research.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would recommend using a single-shot `QTimer` that you restart each time `mouseMoveEvent` is called. Set the timeout to some threshold of your choosing. For example:

```
class Widget : public QWidget
{
public:
  Widget(QWidget *parent = nullptr)
    : QWidget(parent)
  {
    setMouseTracking(true);
    mTimer.setInterval(500);
    mTimer.setSingleShot(true);
    connect(&mTimer, &QTimer::timeout, [] {
      qDebug("Mouse stopped moving!!!");
    });
  }

  void mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent *event) override
  {
    mTimer.start();
  }

private:
  QTimer mTimer;
};
```

Comment: Excellent! This is just what I want! Thank you very much!